# VSCode: How to disable some languages appearing in "select language mode" list?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd appreciate your help.

How to disable some languages appearing in "select language mode" list?
In other words, ow to show in "select language mode" just my favorite languages?

What I'm looking for would be similar to the functionality available in notepad++ (screenshot below).

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: you can't, when the list is shown type the start characters of the language wanted

Comment: I have used VSC for years and almost never used the `Select Language` command, why do you use it often

Comment: "I have used VSC for years and almost never used the `Select Language` command, why do you use it often". ==>I'm learning code and tweaking around. By default VSCode creates a new file as plain text, and having a `Select Language` limited to the languages of my interest seems convenient, like I could do in Notepad++.

Comment: when you create a file give it an extension, use the `New File` button in the `Explorer View`